# Formatting long structured text string from Jira Atlassian issue url in php

Tags: php, object, jira

Im wondering if there is an easy way to access the information in a huge string i have, the string is structured, for the purpose of people reviewing it i put line breaks and space but this is just one huge single line of text that's returned:

First this is how i access the Jira API:

```
$username = 'xxx';
$password = 'xxx';

$url = 'https://xxx.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/Issue/Bug-5555';

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$username:$password");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);

$issue_list = (curl_exec($curl));
echo $issue_list;
```

Now that returns a huge string which when broken down looks like this:

```
{"expand":
"renderedFields,names,schema,transitions,operations,editmeta,changelog",
"id":"16935",
"self":"https://xxx.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/issue/16935",
"key":"xx-5555",
"fields":
        {"summary":"Dialog boxes shouldn't be on top.",
        "progress":
                    {"progress":0,
                    "total":0
                    },
        "timetracking":{},
        "issuetype":
                        {"self":"https://xxx.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/issuetype/1",
                    "id":"1",
                    "description":"A problem which impairs or prevents the functions of the product.",
                    "iconUrl":"https://xxx.atlassian.net/images/icons/bug.gif",
                    "name":"Bug",
                    "subtask":false
                    },
        "timespent":null,
        "reporter":
                    {"self":"https://xxx.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/user?username=xxx%40xxx.com",
                    "name":"xxx@xx.com",
                    "emailAddress":"xxx@xxx.com",
                    "avatarUrls":{"16x16":"https://xxx.atlassian.net/secure/useravatar?size=small&avatarId=10122",
                    "48x48":"https://xxx.atlassian.net/secure/useravatar?avatarId=10122"},
                    "displayName":"xxx",
                    "active":true
                    },
        "created":"2012-08-25T18:39:27.760-0600",
        "updated":"2012-08-31T16:47:38.761-0600",
        "priority":
                    {"self":"https://xxx.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/priority/6",
                    "iconUrl":"http://dl.dropbox.com/u/xxx/3-green.png",
                    "name":"3 - Medium Priority",
                    "id":"6"
                    },
        "description":"\"loading \" dialog is always on top, so is the \"Updating database\" dialog.\r\n\r\n\r\nThis is annoying. It shouldn't be on top and/or you should be able to easily minimize the window.",
        "issuelinks":[], etc etc etc
```

Now im a basic php user so please try and keep the replies simplistic if possible, before i go down the route of parsing the whole document which will be difficult for me as im not familiar with parsing i was wondering if there was an easy way to access the values.

what im thinking is something like this:

```
foreach($issue_list->issues as $issue) {
    echo "summary" . $issue->summary;
    echo "updated" . $issue->updated;
    echo "created" . $issue->created;
    echo "description" . $issue->description;
}
```

Now this might be wishful thinking but i seen an article where i guy done something similar but i cant figure it out, here is the article:
http://www.lornajane.net/posts/2012/using-jiras-rest-api-to-create-a-dashboard

Also if it is possible, how would i access the reporter > displayName value since that's 2 indents deep, would it be $issue->reporter->displayName;

Finally one quick other question, if im echoing the description, how do i get it to obey the /r/r/r/r/r/n and /" so it prints it out with line breaks and removes those special characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a JSON (JavaScript Object Notation - [more info here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON)) string, you could probably use `json_decode` (documented [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)) to convert it into a PHP object and then easily index it.

I don't have your full string but you can probably try something along the lines of:

```
$jiraIssue = json_decode($theString);
echo $jiraIssue["id"];
```

Now, since objects are contained inside of objects, you'll probably have to go through `"fields"` before you can access `"summary"`.

You can pass `true` as a second parameter if you'd prefer to deal with `array`s instead of `object`s.

Comment: thanks Mate exactly what i needed, so pleased i can access the info this way, should save a ton of work, this is what worked:

$issue_list = curl_exec($curl);
$issue_json = json_decode($issue_list);
echo "Description" . $issue_json->fields->description;

Comment: Now it's time to mark all these issues in Jira as "Cannot Reproduce" or "Will Not Fix" ;)  Glad to help!